# Separating (n) keys from array of objects into a single array with keys names

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I need to perform filter in the array of objects to get all the keys. Although, whenever there is a obj inside of that key, I would need to get the key name and concat with the key name from the obj, so for example:

```
const data = [ id: 5, name: "Something", obj: { lower: True, higher: False } ]
result = ["id", "name", "obj.lower", "obj.higher"]
```

I could manage to do the above code, but, if there is more objs inside the data, I would need to keep adding a if condition inside of my logic, I would like to know if there is any other way, so it doesn't matter how many objects I have inside the objects, It will concat always.

The code I used from the above mention:

```
const itemsArray = [
      { id: 1, item: "Item 001", obj: { name: 'Nilton001', message: "Free001", obj2: { test: "test001" } } },
      { id: 2, item: "Item 002", obj: { name: 'Nilton002', message: "Free002", obj2: { test: "test002" } } },
      { id: 3, item: "Item 003", obj: { name: 'Nilton003', message: "Free003", obj2: { test: "test003" } } },
    ];

const csvData = [    
    Object.keys(itemsArray[0]),
    ...itemsArray.map(item => Object.values(item))
].map(e => e.join(",")).join("\n")

// Separating keys
let keys = []
const allKeys = Object.entries(itemsArray[0]);
for (const data of allKeys) {
    if (typeof data[1] === "object") {
        const gettingObjKeys = Object.keys(data[1]);
        const concatingKeys = gettingObjKeys.map((key) => data[0] + "." + key);        
        keys.push(concatingKeys);
    } else {
        keys.push(data[0])
    }
}

//Flating
const flattingKeys = keys.reduce((acc, val: any) => acc.concat(val), []);
```

What I would like to achieve, lets suppose I have this array of object:

```
const data = 
[
   { id: 10, obj: {name: "Name1", obj2: {name2: "Name2", test: "Test"}}}
   ...
]

Final result = ["id", "obj.name", "obj.obj2.name2", "obj.obj2.test"]

OBS: The first obj contains all the keys I need, no need to loop through other to get KEYS.
```

I would like to achieve, all the keys from the first object of the array, and if there is objects inside of objects, I would like to concat the obj names (obj.obj2key1)

Comment: Your `data` isn;t valid js ? Please add a [mre]

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map the key or the keys of the nested objects.

```js
const
    getKeys = object => Object
        .entries(object)
        .flatMap(([k, v]) => v && typeof v === 'object'
            ? getKeys(v).map(s => `${k}.${s}`)
            : k
        ),
    getValues = object => Object
        .entries(object)
        .flatMap(([k, v]) => v && typeof v === 'object'
            ? getValues(v)
            : v
        ),
    data = { id: 1, item: "Item 001", obj: { name: 'Nilton001', message: "Free001", obj2: { test: "test001" } } },
    keys = getKeys(data),
    values = getValues(data);

console.log(keys);
console.log(values);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This worked better since it doesn't check if value from key is null

Comment: Could you add a code that will do the same, although it will get the value of the items separeted by commas? `[1, "Item 001", "Nilton001, "Free001]...`

Comment: @NiltonSchumacherF, it is nearly the same without mapping prepending key.

Answer (score 2):

something like this

```js
const itemsArray = [
      { id: 1, item: "Item 001", obj: { name: 'Nilton001', message: "Free001", obj2: { test: "test001" } } },
      { id: 2, item: "Item 002", obj: { name: 'Nilton002', message: "Free002", obj2: { test: "test002" } } },
      { id: 3, item: "Item 003", obj: { name: 'Nilton003', message: "Free003", obj2: { test: "test003" } } },
    ];
    
const item = itemsArray[0];

const getAllKeys = (obj, prefix=[]) => {
 if(typeof obj !== 'object'){
   return prefix.join('.')
 }
 return Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([k, v]) => getAllKeys(v, [...prefix, k]))
}

console.log(getAllKeys(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP solution can be simplified by accepting a prefix param (the parent key) and a results param (defaulted to `[]` and passed into the recursion) to do the flattening...

```js
let obj = { key0: 'v0', key1: { innerKey0: 'innerV0', innerInner: { deeplyNested: 'v' } }, key2: { anotherInnerKey: 'innerV' } }

function recursiveKeys(prefix, obj, result=[]) {
  let keys = Object.keys(obj);
  keys.forEach(key => {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object')
      recursiveKeys(key, obj[key], result);
    else
      result.push(`${prefix}.${key}`)
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(recursiveKeys('', obj))
```

Comment: For multiple objects inside objects, this didn't work.

Comment: @NiltonSchumacherF - edited to add data with multiple top-level objects and deeply nested objects.  Works to the extent I understand the objective of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getKeys(obj) {
  return Object.keys((typeof obj === 'object' && obj) || {}).reduce((acc, key) => {
    if (obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      const keys = getKeys(obj[key]);
      keys.forEach((k) => acc.add(`${key}.${k}`));
    } else {
      acc.add(key);
    }
    return acc;
  }, new Set());
}

// accumulate the keys in a set (the items of the array may
// have different shapes). All of the possible keys will be
// stored in a set
const s = itemsArray.reduce(
  (acc, item) => new Set([...acc, ...getKeys(item)]),
  new Set()
);

console.log('Keys => ', Array.from(s));
```

Comment: Could you do a fix please, in case the key is there but the value is null, I still want to get the key, although I got and null error

Comment: I believe it works for `null` values too. Do you have an example of a case where it fails?

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion as follows. Since `typeof([1,3,5])` is `object`, we also have to confirm that `value` is not an array, `!Array.isArray(value)`:

```js
const obj = { id: 10, obj: {name: "Name1", obj2: {name2: "Name2", test: "Test"}}};

const getKeys = (o,p) => Object.entries(o).flatMap(([key,value]) => 
    typeof(value) === 'object' && !Array.isArray(value) ? 
        getKeys(value, (p?`${p}.`:"") + key) : 
        (p ? `${p}.`: "") + key
);

console.log( getKeys(obj) );
```